# handlebars js not rendering array

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I've been working for a while to try and render an array from an express app that I have running but I get no errors but nothing displayed.

Here is my handlebars template:

```
<h3>Registered Users:</h3>
<h5>{{users}}</h5>
<ul class="list-group">
    {{#each users}}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        {{this.fields.username}}
    </li>

    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Here is my express code that returns users.

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  api.getUsers(function(response, body){
    console.log(body);
    res.render('users/list', { 'users': body });
  });
});
```

At first I thought the users array wasn't getting passed through from express correctly, but in the template you can see that I just displayed users, and the object displayed was what I thought it would be.

But the list of users is not getting rendered, even though there's at least one element in the array. Any ideas? I'm sure it's something small I'm missing..

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but I don't think you need the `this` in `this.fields.username`.

Answer (score 3):

I would have to agree with @Joe Attardi, your template should look more like this:

```
<h3>Registered Users:</h3>
<h5>{{users}}</h5>
<ul class="list-group">
    {{#each users as |user|}} <!-- get each user as user from users -->
    <li class="list-group-item">
        {{user.username}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks! I tried this, but even when I just did {{user}} inside the block to see if anything would show up, nothing did. Is it possible the object I have is not being interpreted as an array or something?

Comment: If that's not working the, my best guess is that your api.getUsers function is not returning your data. process of elimination. first remove the call to api.getUsers(), just create a users stub object, render it and see if handlebars shows anything. 
var testUsers = [{username:'jsmith'}, {username:'janesmith'}]
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('users/list', { users: testUsers });